# Is there a way to reuse attr inputType?

Tags: android, attr

I have a customized ViewGroup and it contains a EditText.
I want to set inputType for EditText in xml. But I don't want to re-define input type. How can I do that?

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyEditText);
a.getInt(android.R.attr.inputType, EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
```

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Error, because there's no inputType attr in my ViewGroup.
I also have tried this:

```
int[] attrsReuse = new int[] { android.R.attr.inputType /* index 0 */};
Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
TypedArray ta = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrsReuse);
```

The same error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the relevant code bits (XML layout, etc.)?

Comment: @curtisLoew thanks for your response. I find a way to do this. See my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

I find a way to do this.

Add this to **attrs.xml**:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyEditText" >
    <attr name="android:inputType"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Add this to view in layout:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Then I can get this attr in my cusom view class:

```
int inputType = a.getInt(R.styleable.MyEditText_android_inputType, EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
if (inputType != EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL) {
    mInputEditText.setInputType(inputType);
}
```

Comment: ```if (inputType != EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL) {
            mEditTextView.setInputType(inputType);
        }```

Comment: Works as charm.

Comment: Note: use your custom view name + _android_inputType instead of ClearableEditText_android_inputType.